# gpasswd and groups commands give conflicting results

Tags: arch-linux, group

Following commands are run with user alp in an Arch Linux system:

```
[alp@archlinux ~]$ groups
uucp
[alp@archlinux ~]$ groups alp
uucp
[alp@archlinux ~]$ sudo gpasswd -d alp uucp
Removing user alp from group uucp
gpasswd: user 'alp' is not a member of 'uucp'
[alp@archlinux ~]$ id alp
uid=1000(alp) gid=14(uucp) groups=14(uucp)
```

I removed alp from uucp, rebooted and then run these commands so everything should be refreshed.

My /etc/group file shows uucp group has no associated users:

```
uucp:x:14:
```

In practice I know that I am in uucp group because I run a process which can read/write to /dev/ttyUSB0 device file. I couldn't do it otherwise because /dev/ttyUSB0 has permissions:

```
[alp@archlinux ~]$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0 Dec  8 12:51 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

What is the reason for this conflicting info?

**Edit:**

@PiedPiper, running `grpconv` doesn't make any difference.

@Mark Plotnik:

```
[alp@archlinux ~]$ grep ^alp: /etc/passwd
alp:x:1000:14::/home/alp:/bin/bash
```

Comment: If you do `grep ^alp: /etc/passwd`, does it show group 14?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes it does. See my edit.

Comment: It looks like `login` is doing `initgroups("user", gid)`. I'll look through the code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `id` shows the groups you were in when you *logged in*. You retain those permission for your whole session . If you log out and back in again it will show the correct groups.
Note: if you add yourself to a new group, you also need to re-login for the group to take effect

Comment: I removed alp from uucp, rebooted and then run these commands so everything should be refreshed but it isn't.

Comment: I don't know what grpconv is

Comment: grpconv doesn't make any difference